# Download images directly to mobile through a button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, mobile

I wonder can a webpage generate a button that can let users download images and save directly into the photo library of their mobile device? Expected not to open another webpage that only displaying the image, but let them download a package of images into the phone. Can I actually do that?

Comment: No, because then someone would make a page to download a billion photos to your phone.

Comment: no even can ask for privileges before download?

Comment: I agree with sachleen - this is almost certainly impossible.  Downloading of any sort is difficult to do without opening some other window.

Comment: @jeff9888 - No.  There is no way for them to grant it, and there is nothing you could do with there permission.

Comment: You're both wrong. See @Marshall's answer below.

Comment: @DannyBeckett no. Marshall's answer won't work on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use php `header` to include the `Content-Disposition` to tell the browser to download as a file.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.png"');
```

(example for a PNG)

The user will click download-photo.php for example and that script will deliver these headers and it will also need to get the file contents of the image and include as the payload of the response.

Comment: I tried this before, but it only show me the image file on a webpage, not to download. This can be done on a regular PC's web browser but not mobile's. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's ultimately up to the browser what happens, so you're limited to that.

Comment: I tried this. Image is downloading with same memory size. But it's always showing 'Invalid Image'.